# Sending image to fax machine from android applicaton

Tags: android

I have a requirement that i need to take a picture from the android device and i need to send this image to a fax machine. Can any body help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is, unfortunately far too vague to be reasonably answered on a Q&A web site. Please update your question to indicate what you have tried. If you are simply stuck on how to proceed, indicate what you _thought_ might work and why you think it won't. In other words, give us something to go on (beyond designing your app). If you do, please flag this for moderator attention to be re-opened.